# Coloring checkbuttons text in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to add a checkbox to a python chart, to check the lines to be displayed or hidden.

I found the code below that works just fine, except one detail, that is annoyingly difficult for me to find out, I already have a few weeks since I am trying to do that: besides the checkboxes and the series names, I would like to also have the line colors along to the text, to be able to visually identify which line is which series.

Initially I tried to show the legend over the text, next to the checkboxes, but the legend would move if the window is resized, and that would not be feasible to implement.

My feeling is that there should be a way to add the line colors display within the function that creates the checkboxes, can anyone give me some suggestions on how to do that? The function is:

```
def func(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()
```

The link with the full code is:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/widgets/check_buttons.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for idx, text in enumerate(check.labels):
    text.set_color(lines[idx].get_color())
```

Add this bit of code after instantiating `CheckButtons`. It will color the text like you want it to.

*Old, worse solution:*

`labels = [str(line.get_label()) + ", " + str(line.get_color()) for line in lines]`

Comment: Thanks for that answer. But it does not seem to work.
With the "for" statement, I get the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_color'"
And with the "old, worse solution" it writes the color code next to the labels.
Still, that got me to a good track, I'll see if I can solve any of the 2 errors.

But I got it working.

Comment: But I got it working. I will add the solution here, hopefully it's understood, in case someone else will have this error:

The "lines" list was a lit of lists, each line being a list woth one item.
So I made a list of STR, from the list, using the code below:

flat_lines = [item for sublist in lines for item in sublist]

Then, used the flat_lines in the code, instead the "regular" lines.

Comment: @AndreiUngurean My code works with the example you provided ; in it, `lines` isn't a list of lists, so I didn't run into that issue. Glad it's all sorted out though, remember to set it as the accepted answer to close the thread.